# Problems accessing IBM Containers at UK Data Center

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

Note: This is a question related to Bluemix Container service, it is not generic to Docker.

I have a linux environment with cf and ice tools installed and working correctly with US_SOUTH Data Center. I changed the login parameters to UK Data Center and now, although it login correctly to Container service it fails when executing any command with 404.

```
Command failed with container cloud service
404 Not Found: Requested route ('api-ice.eu-gb.bluemix.net') does not exist.
```

I did the login following documentation:

```
ice login -a https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net -H https://api-ice.eu-gb.bluemix.net/v2/containers -R registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net
```

And as I said the login is successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for London:

`ice login -H containers-api.eu-gb.bluemix.net -R registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net -a api.eu-gb.bluemix.net`

For US South:

`ice login -H containers-api.ng.bluemix.net -R registry.ng.bluemix.net -a api.ng.bluemix.net`

`api-ice.eu-gb.bluemix.net` should throw a 404. When we closed our our public beta we changed our API server to use the `containers-api.{domain}` pattern. (While temporarily leaving `api-ice.ng.bluemix.net` available for folks needing to migrate from the beta.)

We are currently updating the docs. Thanks for pointing this out.